# C#: trying a simple project

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am new to C#. I wanted to do a simple program with some type of loops. 
I wanted my program to loop through the numbers that the user enters and if it is less than a number then write keep guessing,but once they enter the number 25 i wanted it to say Merry Christmas..  Please Help

```
int number;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 20 through 25");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}  while (number < 25);
```

C# Beginner

Comment: FYI: Console.ReadLine() will require the user to enter a sequence of digits and the <enter> key.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
int number = 0;
while (number != 25)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 20 through 25");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (number != 25)
        Console.WriteLine("Keep guessing");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Merry Christmas");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your question is, but I've got a couple of comments:

1. An exception will be thrown if the user enters something that can't be parsed as an int. Fix this by using TryParse.
2. As written, the loop will exit if the user enters a number greater than 25, such as 26.

Modified code:

```
int number;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 20 through 25");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);
} while (number != 25);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are never going to use the input as a number, it is safer to just leave it a string, expecialy since you are only checking for "25" exactly.
Also, adding a way to exit without entering 25 would be nice for the user, like entering a blank line for example.

Here is how I would write it:

> ```
>     static void x()
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 20 through 25");
>         string input = null;
>         while(true)
>         {
>             input = Console.ReadLine();
>             if (input == null || input.Length == 0)
>                 break; // will exit the loop
>             if (input != "25")
>                 Console.WriteLine("Keep guessing");
>             else
>             {
>                 Console.WriteLine("Merry Christmas");
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
int number;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 20 through 25");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
} while (number < 25);

if (number == 25)
    Console.WriteLine("Merry Christmas");
```

Comment: What if they enter 26?  The loop will exit on values over 25 and there is still the issue of what if the user enters nothing?

Answer (score 0):

```
int number;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 20 through 25");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
} while (number != 25);

Console.WriteLine("Merry Christmas");
```

Would be correct if you want them to be able to enter numbers higher than 25.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int myNumber;

        Guess: Console.Write("Guess a number between 20 through 25: ");
        myNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            while(myNumber != 25)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Keep Guessing");
                goto Guess;
            }
            Console.Write("Merry Christmas");

        Console.ReadKey();
```